# Can anyone help me in completing this generic method to update from one list to another list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to pass 2 list variables as parameters to generic method. Which has to loop through all the properties of 1st list and assign the value to 2nd list?

I have taken this Example in my case:

Say I have Customer as my entity class given below:

```
class Customer
{
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string custPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have 2 list objects of type customer. Let first list be list coming from view and second list be the existing list from data base.

First list coming from UI that is from view be something like below.

```
List<Customer> CustomerListToUpdate = new List<Customer>() 
{
    new Customer { CustId = 1,Name = "XYZ" ,custPhoneNumber = "12345"},
    new Customer { CustId = 2,Name = "XYZ" ,custPhoneNumber = "12345"},
    new Customer { CustId = 3,Name = "XYZ" ,custPhoneNumber = "12345"}
};
```

Second list coming from Data Base be like below

```
List<Customer> extistingCustomerList = new List<Customer>() 
{
    new Customer { CustId = 1,Name = "abc" ,custPhoneNumber = "56789"},
    new Customer { CustId = 2,Name = "abc" ,custPhoneNumber = "56789"},
    new Customer { CustId = 3,Name = "abc" ,custPhoneNumber = "56789"}
};
```

Now I am trying to write a generic method that take above 2 list as the parameters and then assigns the new value to the existing list and perform .SaveChanges() method of my db context object.

Basically I am not able to complete this method :

```
class UpdateMethod<T>
{
    public void updatemethod<T>(T UpdatedCustomerList, T extistingCustomerList)
    {
        foreach (var item in UpdatedCustomerList)
        {
            //I need to assign the values of UpdatedCustomerList to extistingCustomerList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part you want to be generic?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov updatemethod I want to make a generic method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov class UpdateMethod<T>
{
    public void updatemethod<T>(T UpdatedCustomerList, T extistingCustomerList)
    {
        foreach (var item in UpdatedCustomerList)
        {
            //I need to assign the values of UpdatedCustomerList to extistingCustomerList
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Christos did u delete your post?

Comment: @SanjuRao yeah I deleted it because I didn't find a way to help you. I am sorry :(

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What other types, besides `List<Customer>` would you pass to `UpdateMethod`?

Comment: Why do you want to modify existing entities? If the entities in `UpdatedCustomerList` contain all the data you need you can simply **attach** them to your existing `DbContext`, EF will manage the update itself.

Comment: @Pragmateek. In my controller when I get the Customer Details. It will be having only limited values. and when I pass this and perform .SaveChanges() on my dbContext object it throws me error. So what I am trying to do is fetching the existing row based on my primary key Id and assigning the new value to those columns that is coming from view. and doing calling ".SaveChange()" on my db context object

Comment: @Christos thank You very much I appreciate for your effort in helping me. U rock!!!

Comment: @SanjuRao You welcome dude ! I hope someone could help you more.

Comment: @dcastro Can you go through my comments that I have answer to Pragmateek. Hope that may help u in understanding some what.If not please let me know I will edit my post.

Comment: @SanjuRao So I fear you can't be completely generic: how would you detect a change in an entity? Either you decide that you will always update some properties and you need to provide a list of them (their names should be enough) or you need to have some conventions, like null meaning "not modified", but this is not perfect: how do you tell the difference between "previously null value not updated" and "was not null and has been updated to null"? I guess you are in a n-tier scenario so you could introduce a basic change-tracking system to know which properties have changed.

Comment: @Pragmateek basically I don't end up in null values pragmateek. Because most of the columns in table are non null able. and if its nullit would default to 0 or empty string based on the data type.

Comment: @Pragmateek I was basically trying to implement a generic function which loops to each properties in the list and then to rows. By this way I planned to get the type of the properties from both the list. If they are matching. Then Update old value in list1 with new value from list2. But I hanged up while writing the for each loop in my UpdateMethod(). :(

Answer (score 0):

Then you can change your method to:

```
public void updatemethod<T>(List<T> UpdatedCustomerList, List<T> extistingCustomerList) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var item in UpdatedCustomerList)
        {

            var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            var idProp = properties.First(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Id"));
            var toUpdate = extistingCustomerList.First(c => (int)idProp.GetValue(c) == (int)idProp.GetValue(item));
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                prop.SetValue(toUpdate, prop.GetValue(item));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you using Entity Framework you can do this to update database like this:

```
class UpdateMethod<T>
{

    updatemethod<T>(List<T> UpdatedCustomerList, List<T> extistingCustomerList)
    {
        var _context = new YourDbContex() // You db context
        foreach (var item in UpdatedCustomerList)
        {
            _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Check this generic repository for Entity Framework https://github.com/filipmate/user.crud/blob/master/User.CRUD/Repositories/Repository.cs

Comment: basically I am using .edmx class. according to you where Can I create this IEntity interface so that It will be applicable to all the .edmx files. I am confused how to processed :(.

Comment: I edited my answer so now it doesnt need interface. It works but it assume that key column ends with Id

Comment: Thank You very much. I will implement this tomorrow and mark your solution.

Comment: Be aware that setting the `State` to `Modified` will update all the properties which is not what you want if I understand well, it's why I've proposed to use `Attach` instead...